# How to make a sweet alert in asp.net?

Tags: sweetalert

Actually i tried to make a sweet alert when i press the button (Back to Home) but still i have troubles.

I use the fllowing syntax:

```
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="background-color:blue" asp-controller="Home"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to come back home?')">
                <span class="material-icons">home</span> Back to Home
    </a>
```

The above syntax works well, but i need to be more beatiful as sweet alert.

Please let me know your idea.
I did many ways but it seems that some thing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We solved the problem as following:

Actually in this case it is better to use button tag:

```
<div class="pb-1 pt-1 float-left">
            <button class="btn btn-info" id="test">
                <span class="material-icons">home</span> Back to Home
            </button>
</div>
```

Then in a javscript file we attached the following sweet alert function:

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure you go back to home?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover your data!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
        function () {
            location.href = "/Home/Index";
        });
});
```

And do not forget to attach the sweet alert library from the following links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

or you can directly inculde the above links in _layout.cshtml file, then it will be available for all the WebApp.

I hope it will be useful for others.